# Why can't I add a Todo using Apollo Link State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Todo never gets added. Visibility Filter works & remote Coinbase fetch works.

Here's my repo

https://github.com/deadcoder0904/apollo-coinbase

& here's the same code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/apollographql/apollo-link-state/tree/master/examples/todo

The example is similar to the codesandbox one with just Remote URI for a fetch from coinbase APIs for some coins

I’ve copied the same example

Just 2 changes

1st change is I added a HTTPLink for fetching Remote Data using Coinbase API

2nd change is I didn’t use Apollo-Boost & explicitly imported everything else

I don't understand the difference bcz the code is literally similar (welp they are using apollo-boost & i have used every single chunk differently & gobbled together)

The addTodo mutation is not working in TodoForm.js personally :)

## TodoForm.js

```
import React from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";

const ADD_TODO = gql`
  mutation addTodo($text: String!) {
    addTodo(text: $text) @client {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const TodoForm = () => (
  <Mutation mutation={ADD_TODO}>
    {addTodo => {
      let input;
      return (
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!input.value.trim()) return;
            addTodo({ variables: { text: input.value } });
            input.value = "";
          }}
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={node => {
              input = node;
            }}
          />
          <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
        </form>
      );
    }}
  </Mutation>
);

export { TodoForm };
```

The error is -

> [Network error]: TypeError:
>   Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_graphql_tag**["gql"]) is not a
>   function. (In
>   'Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_graphql_tag**["gql"])(_templateObject)',
>   'Object(**WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_graphql_tag**["gql"])' is an
>   instance of Object) on App.js:46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I guess I have to get used to reading the logs properly.

I made one small mistake in `./resolvers/todos` file & everywhere else it was fine

I actually imported gql as a named export like -

`import { gql } from 'graphql-tag';`

when I was supposed to use default export like -

`import gql from 'graphql-tag';`

Answer (score 1):

It thinks `gql` is something other than a function (probably undefined).  Should be easy enough to print it out and see.  I wouldn't be surprised if you have a bad version of graphql-tag.  Set it to a fixed version in package.json

Comment: but it works for everything else like Fetching Coinbase API & Filter Switching

Comment: I changed it to fixed version but it isn't working :(

Comment: The problem I found right now was I did `import gql from "graphql-tag";` everywhere & in resolvers I did `import { gql } from "graphql-tag";`. Anyways it works now :)